# If $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n=\{x\}$, then $\{U_1,U_2,...\}$ is a local base at $x$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $X$ be a countably compact space, $x\in X$, and $U_1,U_2,...$ open sets such that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n=\{x\}$. Then $\{U_1,U_2,...\}$ is a local base at $x$.

We take an open set $A\subseteq X$ with $x\in A$. So $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n\subseteq A$. I want to prove there's some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in U_n\subseteq A.$

I don't really know what we could do here.

Countably compact is every open countable cover has a finite subcover. I also have proved that it's equivalently to each sequence has an accumulation point. And closed subspaces of $X$ are also countably compact.

Could someone give a hint?

Comment: What's your definition of local base?

Comment: I edited it. It's just some $U_n$ is contained in $A$. @graydad

Comment: And $A$ is an arbitrary open set containing $x$?

Comment: A local base at $x$ is a family $F$ of nbhds of $x$ such that for any nbhd $V$ of $x$ there exists $f\in F$ such that $f\subset V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely false as stated. Let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology on $\Bbb N$; $\langle\Bbb N,\tau\rangle$ is compact. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=\Bbb N\setminus\{n\}$; the sets $U_n$ are open, and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n=\{0\}$, but $\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2\}$ is an open nbhd of $0$ that does not contain any $U_n$.

You can avoid this kind of trivial counterexample by requiring in the statement of the result that $U_n\supseteq U_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. However, even this isn’t enough. J.E. Vaughan, [*Countably compact, locally countable $T_2$-spaces*](http://www.ams.org/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574525-X/S0002-9939-1980-0574525-X.pdf) [PDF], Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. $80$ ($1980$), pp. $147$-$153$, constructs a countably compact Hausdorff space $X$ of cardinality $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ in which every singleton is the intersection of a countable family of open nbhds, but there are no non-trivial convergent sequences. Clearly $X$ is not discrete, so it must have at least one limit point $x$. If there were a countable local base at $x$, we could construct a sequence in $X\setminus\{x\}$ converging to $x$; since $X$ has no non-trivial convergent sequences, however, this is impossible, and therefore $x$ cannot have a countable local base.

Comment: Thank you very much. This false statement was in Willard's General Topology, don't remember edition.
http://i.imgur.com/y7bXjQM.png

Comment: @TRmate: You’re very welcome. Yes, that’s a genuine mistake in Willard. (There aren’t too many.) If you replace *countably compact* by *compact Hausdorff* and make the sets $U_n$ nested, however, the result is true.

Comment: That's good to know.