# If $X$ is countably compact and $\overline{U_{n+1}} \subset U_n$ and $\bigcap U_n = \{x\}$, then $\{U_i\}$ is a nhood base at $x$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**DISCLAIMER:** Be careful not to link [If $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n=\{x\}$, then $\{U_1,U_2,...\}$ is a local base at $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485341/if-displaystyle-bigcap-n-in-mathbbn-u-n-x-then-u-1-u-2-is). This result contains a false variation of this problem.

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a countably compact space with $x \in X$. If $U_1, U_2, \dots$ is a sequence of open sets in $X$ such that $\overline{U_{n+1}} \subset U_n$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n = \{x\}$, then $\{U_1, U_2, \dots \}$ is a nhood base at $x$.

*Proof.*

Let $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of open sets satisfying $\overline{U_{n+1}} \subset U_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty = \{x\}$. Towards a contradiction, suppose the collection $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does *not* form a nhood base at $x$ and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$. My variation is true, from what I gather

Since $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a nbhd base at $x$, then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $U_n \cap (X \setminus U) \neq \varnothing$. So say $x_n \in U_n \cap (X \setminus U)$ for every $n$.

We claim that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is infinite. To see this, suppose not. Suppose $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is finite. If it's finite, then eventually $\{x_n\}$ is constant. But this means there exists $x_0 \in U_n$ for all $U_n$. But this is a contradiction because we assumed $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = \{x\}$.

So then $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is infinite. But since $X$ is countably compact, $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has an accumulation point in $X$.

But beyond this point, I get stuck. Any ideas here? Am I on the right track / have I hand waved things in my proof? I feel close to figuring this out. Any pointers are greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\{U_1, U_2, \dots \}$ is not a nhood base at $x$. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U_n \nsubseteq U$ for all ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Hence $(\overline{U_n} \setminus U)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a chain of non-empty closed subsets of $X$ with empty intersection, which contradicts that $X$ is countably compact.

Comment: I understand that a space $X$ is compact if and only if every collection of closed subsets with the finite intersection property has itself nonempty intersection, but does this extend to countable compactness?

Comment: Yes, a space is countably compact, if and only if every countable collection of closed sets with finite intersection property has non-empty intersection, if and only if every countable open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Alternatively to the above proof you can also mimic the proof of the first equiavalence by choosing a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n \in U_n \setminus U$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (as you already started above). Then show that an accumulation point would be in $(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{U_n}) \setminus U = \emptyset$.